# context initialization failed alfresco, open office failed to connect

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

facing this error on the development server on local host amps are working fine,as error suggests tried trouble-shooting open office (http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/troubleshoot-openoffice.html)   but error still persists.

PS:Before deployment of new amps,I deleted all workflows "delete all workflows imeanit" through admin console.Dont know if this lead to the below error

Edit :  8100 was responsible for jodconverter (used by open office /libre office ) , I disabled converter but still context initialisation failed.

```
org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: failed to start and connect
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess.startAndWait(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:68)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.PooledOfficeManager.start(PooledOfficeManager.java:101)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ProcessPoolOfficeManager.start(ProcessPoolOfficeManager.java:66)
    at org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.content.JodConverterSharedInstance.afterPropertiesSet(JodConverterSharedInstance.java:239)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory$ApplicationContextState.start(ChildApplicationContextFactory.java:809)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.AbstractPropertyBackedBean.start(AbstractPropertyBackedBean.java:1086)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.AbstractPropertyBackedBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPropertyBackedBean.java:625)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:207)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: could not establish connection
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess.startAndWait(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:66)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: could not establish connection
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess.doStartProcessAndConnect(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:147)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess.access$0(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:122)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess$1.run(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:62)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: a process with acceptString 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100' is already running; pid 3288
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcess.start(OfficeProcess.java:74)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcess.start(OfficeProcess.java:67)
    at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess.doStartProcessAndConnect(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:124)
    ... 7 more


    Context initialization failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.facet.SolrFacetServiceImpl.getFacetProperties(SolrFacetServiceImpl.java:348)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.facet.SolrFacetServiceImpl.getPersistedFacetProperties(SolrFacetServiceImpl.java:728)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.facet.SolrFacetServiceImpl.onBootstrap(SolrFacetServiceImpl.java:637)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:207)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-04-12 06:53:40,546 INFO  [org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.cluster.core.ClusteringBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Clustering has shutdown.
2017-04-12 06:53:40,547 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [localhost-startStop-1] Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.extensions.config.xml.XMLConfigService.removeElementReaders(XMLConfigService.java:504)
    at org.springframework.extensions.config.xml.XMLConfigService.destroy(XMLConfigService.java:150)
    at org.springframework.extensions.config.BaseConfigService.onShutdown(BaseConfigService.java:630)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:67)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:207)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:183)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1049)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:586)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5063)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5719)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

*********************Logs AfterDisablingJodconverter***********************

```
2017-04-20 06:47:44,549 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.facet.SolrFacetServiceImpl.getFacetProperties(SolrFacetServiceImpl.java:348)
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.facet.SolrFacetServiceImpl.getPersistedFacetProperties(SolrFacetServiceImpl.java:728)
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.facet.SolrFacetServiceImpl.onBootstrap(SolrFacetServiceImpl.java:637)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:207)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    2017-04-20 06:48:04,139 INFO  [org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.cluster.core.ClusteringBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Clustering has shutdown.
    2017-04-20 06:48:04,140 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [localhost-startStop-1] Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.extensions.config.xml.XMLConfigService.removeElementReaders(XMLConfigService.java:504)
        at org.springframework.extensions.config.xml.XMLConfigService.destroy(XMLConfigService.java:150)
        at org.springframework.extensions.config.BaseConfigService.onShutdown(BaseConfigService.java:630)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:67)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:207)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:183)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1049)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:586)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5063)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5719)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)


at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: There are different issues here, I think. The jodconverter does not start simply because the port is already in use. See the error message: "Socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100' is already running; pid 3288"

Comment: Thanks Marco , 8100 was responsible for jodconverter (used by open office /libre office ) , I disabled converter but still context initialisation failed error is showing up

Answer (score 2):

When you said  "I disabled converter but still context initialisation failed." did you disabled it in /shared/classes/alfresco/extension/subsystems/OOoDirect/default/default/openoffice-transform.properties ? (Or in alfresco-global.properties it work there too)

- ooo.exe=soffice
- ooo.enabled=false
- ooo.host=localhost
- ooo.port=8100

It seems like your alfresco try to connect to soffice but can't because the port 8100 is already in use. Can change that port or you might want to start your soffice as a separated service:

- soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard

You'll need to change the port.

You might have another soffice thread still running, check your process and kill it.

Comment: thanks prignony! after disabling it through alfresco-global , i am not getting jodconverter 8100 port number  issues but still getting context failing error. is this still related to open office or it is something other than this

Comment: Could you post the new log?

Comment: Hard to say with this log, not enough data, you might have something else above that. 
Is your database up and running? Accessible from your server? 

Is your solr engine up and running, with index file accessible?

Did you try to restart your server completely (I mean not only the tomcat but the server itself, has a few alfesco process might still run)

Did you check alfresco.log and catlina.out? Same error there ?